# PHPUnit + Composer folder structure git vs server deploy

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, continuous-delivery

I try to add PHPUnit tests to my existing php project.
Applying the recomended folder structure for phpunit (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/organizing-tests.html), I encounter the following problem deploying it to the server.

### Current setup php+composer without phpunit

Checked out from git Git + composer install:

```
- my.php
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- vendor/
```

I copy php files and vendor folder to a path on the server

Server:

```
- path/my.php
- path/vendor/
```

So the URL is https://server/path/my.php

In my.php I include the composer dependencies like this

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

### New setup with phpunit included

With recomended folder structure for phpunit (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/organizing-tests.html)

Checked out from git Git + composer install:

```
- src/my.php
- tests/mytest.php
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- vendor/
```

In my.php I now include the composer dependencies like this

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

#### Problems with new setup

- If I copy src+vendor/  to path/ the server the URL would be different (https://server/path/src/my.php).
- If I copy src/*.php and vendor/ to path/ I would have to change the require_once upon deployment for it to work.

### Desired result

- tests seperated from src
- accessible via the same URL
- not having to change php file content uppon deployment (CD)

### The closest solution I came up with

Is to not implement recomended directory structure, leave my old structure, and just create a tests/ directory.

### My question

Is there a best practice solution keeping the src+tests directory structure while keeping the same URL and not having to modify src files upon deployment?

Comment: This does not look related to Composer to me, neither to [tag:continuous-delivery]. Why not set the document root to the folder that contains the root scripts to be called?

Comment: I'm also going along with what Nico Hasse commented. The best-practice I know in this scenario is that ***neither*** `src`, `tests` (or `test`), ***nor*** the project folder itself is reachable via HTTP, only dedicated endpoint scripts in their own, isolated directory (sometimes named `public` but that is your choice). The webserver (application server) must have read only access to them (only). Everything else is not only not best-practice, it additionally begs for having security issues from small to large (as in being "Scheunentor" wide open).